# Bash script to count the number of occurances of a string in a file

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have this function in my Bash script

```
 if [ $numberOne -gt 10 ]
        then
                echo "$numberOne has occurred over 10 times"
                echo "email me numberOne"

        elif [ $numberTwo -gt 4 ]
        then    echo "$numberTwo has occurred over 4 times"
                echo "email me numberTwo"

        elif [ $numberThree -gt 4 ]
        then    echo "$numberThree has occurred over 4 times"
                echo "email me numberThree"

        elif [ $numberFour -gt 5 ]
        then    echo "$numberFour has occurred over 5 times"
                echo "email me numberFour"

        else    echo "nothing found yet"
                exit


        fi

}
```

**Info**: I am port checking. I run a script every minute. When a port is found to be used I write it to a file and then read the file. The number of times it's found equates to minutes. 4 times is 4 minutes, I want to know if the port is active more that a number of minutes.

**What I want to do:**

3 numbers will populate a file. At some point one of them will be present more than 4 times and then the rest will also appear. At that point I want an alert when the first of them occurs or [all of them after the first occurrence]. Ideally the alert will be like this: "NumberOne has been open for 4 minutes". And after 1 minute it will be "5 minutes"-until I stop it or a threshold is reached, I don't know yet.

The problem:
The problem here is that when NumberOne occurs more than 10 times AND NumberTwo occurs 4 times after that it only echoes NumberTwo.

I thought I could use `continue` after each `then`, but I can't!

Also: my NumberOne variable. `NumberOne=$(grep -wc "port=51555" monitor.txt)`

Comment: What do you think `elif` means?  I think you just want 5 independent `if` clauses.  But really what you want is an array of numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of occurrences a string has on a file, use `grep -c`:

```
grep -c something file
```

An example application to this is:

```
file="/path/to/file"
numberOne_string="something"
numberOne=$(grep -c "$numberOne_string" "$file")
```

And about your logic the best option I think could only be:

```
if [[ numberOne -gt 10 || numberTwo -gt 4 || numberThree -gt 4 || numberFour -gt 5 ]]; then
    if [[ numberOne -gt 10 ]]; then
        echo "$numberOne has occurred over 10 times"
        echo "email me numberOne"
    fi
    if [[ numberTwo -gt 4 ]]; then
        echo "$numberTwo has occurred over 4 times"
        echo "email me numberTwo"
    fi
    if [[ numberThree -gt 4 ]]; then
        echo "$numberThree has occurred over 4 times"
        echo "email me numberThree"
    fi
    if [[ numberFour -gt 5 ]]; then
        echo "$numberFour has occurred over 5 times"
        echo "email me numberFour"
    fi
else
    echo "nothing found yet"
fi
```

Or a negated version of it.

Another requires a variable:

```
nothing_found=true
if [[ numberOne -gt 10 ]]; then
    echo "$numberOne has occurred over 10 times"
    echo "email me numberOne"
    nothing_found=false
fi
if [[ numberTwo -gt 4 ]]; then
    echo "$numberTwo has occurred over 4 times"
    echo "email me numberTwo"
    nothing_found=false
fi
if [[ numberThree -gt 4 ]]; then
    echo "$numberThree has occurred over 4 times"
    echo "email me numberThree"
    nothing_found=false
fi
if [[ numberFour -gt 5 ]]; then
    echo "$numberFour has occurred over 5 times"
    echo "email me numberFour"
    nothing_found=false
fi
if [[ $nothing_found == true ]]; then
    echo "nothing found yet"
fi
```

Comment: It it more accurate to say `to count the number of lines containing a string`. Try this for example `grep -c "A" <<< "A A"` It prints `1`

Comment: `grep -o -c` should report the actual number of occurrences, but didn't in earlier versions of GNU Coreutils.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking different variables... you don't need `elif` there... Change it with independent `if`'s. For example:

```
if [ $numberOne -gt 10 ]
then
    echo "$numberOne has occurred over 10 times"
    echo "email me numberOne"
fi

if [ $numberTwo -gt 4 ]
then
    echo "$numberTwo has occurred over 4 times"
    echo "email me numberTwo"
if

if [ $numberThree -gt 4 ]
then
    echo "$numberThree has occurred over 4 times"
    echo "email me numberThree"
fi

if [ $numberThree -gt 5 ]
then
    echo "$numberFour has occurred over 5 times"
    echo "email me numberFour"
fi

if [ $numberOne -le 10 -a $numberTwo -le 4 -a $numberThree -le 4 -a $numberFour -le 5 ]
then
    echo "nothing found yet"
    exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refactoring which reduces code duplication.

```
found=false
while read variable count; do
    value=${!$variable}
    if [ "$value" -gt "$count" ]; then
        echo "$value occurred more than $count times"
        echo "email me $variable"
        found=true
    fi
done <<____HERE
    numberOne  10
    numberTwo   4
    numberThree 4
    numberFour  5
____HERE

if ! $found; then
    echo "Nothing found yet"
fi
```

If you don't have Bash, you can use `eval value="\$$variable"` instead.

If you want to populate the variables on the fly, you could do the `grep -c` inside the loop, and put e.g. a regex, or just the port number, in the first column of the here document instead.